# Headless jasmine testing with intellij

Tags: javascript, testing, intellij-idea, jasmine

Is there a way to run headless jasmine JavaScript tests from IntelliJ? I've seen the jstestdriver plugin and that works for in browser testing, but I couldn't find a way to run headless jasmine tests inside the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a class to parse the js test driver config and generate a spec for the jasmine file. Then I used gradle's envjs plugin run the spec file.